# Show/Hide table header using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Basically I have two different type of header based on the contents of the table when looping through each items:

**JS CODE:**

```
if (idLayer == "nss") {
    var tabs = [];
    for (var layerId in layers) {

        var results = layers[layerId];
        idResults[idLayer + layerId] = results;
        var useHeaderComm = false;
        var count = results.length;
        var label = "", content = "";
        var resultsId = idLayer + layerId;
        switch (layerId) {
            case "2":
                label = "New Sale Sites(" + count + ")";                    
                if (count == 0) break;
                    content += "<table><tr id='headerComm'><th>Location</th><th>Planning Area</th><th>Development Type</th><th>GPR</th><th>Site Area</th><th>Allowable GFA</th><th>Office GFA</th><th>Retail GFA</th><th>Other GFA</th></tr>";
                    content += "<table><tr id='headerResi'><th>Location</th><th>Planning Area</th><th>Development Type</th><th>GPR</th><th>Site Area</th><th>Estimated DU</th></tr>";
                for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                    if (latlng !== 'Null') {
                        var attributes = results[j].feature.attributes;
                        var resultsId = idLayer + layerId;
                        if(attributes["LAND_USE"] == "COMM" || attributes["LAND_USE"] == "OFF" )
                        {
                            content += "<tr>";
                            content += "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showFeature(\"" + resultsId + "\"," + j + ")'>" + attributes["LOCATION"] + "</a></td>";              
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["PLANNING_AREA"] + "</td>";
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["LAND_USE"] + "</td>";
                            if(attributes["GPR"] != "Null" && attributes["GPR"] != "" && attributes["GPR"] != undefined && attributes["GPR"] != "null")
                            {
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["GPR"] + "</td>";                                           
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            content += "<td>N.A</td>";
                            }
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["SITE_AREA"] + "</td>";
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["ALLOWABLE_GFA"] + "</td>";
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["OFFICE_GFA"] + "</td>";
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["RETAIL_GFA"] + "</td>";
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["HOTEL_GFA"] + "</td>";
                            content += "</tr>"; 
                            useHeaderComm = true; 
                        }else
                        {                                                                     
                            content += "<tr>";
                            content += "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showFeature(\"" + resultsId + "\"," + j + ")'>" + attributes["LOCATION"] + "</a></td>";              
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["PLANNING_AREA"] + "</td>";
                            content += "<td>" + attributes["LAND_USE"] + "</td>";
                            if(attributes["GPR"] != "Null" && attributes["GPR"] != "" && attributes["GPR"] != undefined && attributes["GPR"] != "null")
                            {
                                content += "<td>" + attributes["GPR"] + "</td>";                                           
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                content += "<td>N.A</td>";
                            }
                                content += "<td>" + attributes["SITE_AREA"] + "</td>";
                            if(attributes["ESTIMATED_DU"] != "Null" && attributes["ESTIMATED_DU"] != "" && attributes["ESTIMATED_DU"] != undefined && attributes["ESTIMATED_DU"] != "null")
                            {
                                content += "<td>" + attributes["ESTIMATED_DU"] + "</td>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                content += "<td>N.A</td>";
                            }
                                content += "</tr>"; 
                                useHeaderComm = false; 
                        }
                    }
                    if(useHeaderComm == true)
                    {
                        $('.headerResi').hide();
                    }else
                    {
                        $('.headerComm').hide();
                    }

                }
                content += "</table>";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is loop through each items in the results and display the table header based on some attributes.

For example, if the `LAND_USE` was `"COMM"` or `"OFF"` the table header used should be `tr` with the id of `headerComm`.

However, for these codes, both the header just displaying without hide or show. I wonder why is it so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using id for your `<tr>` so, your code should be,

```
if(useHeaderComm == true)
{
    $('#headerResi').hide();
}
else
{
    $('#headerComm').hide();
}
```

And one more thing. You no need add another `<table>` two times in this code,

```
content += "<table><tr id='headerComm'><th>Location</th><th>Planning Area</th><th>Development Type</th><th>GPR</th><th>Site Area</th><th>Allowable GFA</th><th>Office GFA</th><th>Retail GFA</th><th>Other GFA</th></tr>";
content += "<table><tr id='headerResi'><th>Location</th><th>Planning Area</th><th>Development Type</th><th>GPR</th><th>Site Area</th><th>Estimated DU</th></tr>";
```

it should be,

```
content += "<table><tr id='headerComm'><th>Location</th><th>Planning Area</th><th>Development Type</th><th>GPR</th><th>Site Area</th><th>Allowable GFA</th><th>Office GFA</th><th>Retail GFA</th><th>Other GFA</th></tr>";
content += "<tr id='headerResi'><th>Location</th><th>Planning Area</th><th>Development Type</th><th>GPR</th><th>Site Area</th><th>Estimated DU</th></tr>";
```

Comment: Oh ya, my mistake. Thanks for spotting the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you are doing your condition, the element is not appended the the DOM. jQuery only search in DOM or on created element.

I'd suggest to check which 1 to show after appending it to the DOM :

```
$(selector).append(content);
if(useHeaderComm == true)
{
    $('.headerResi').hide();
}else
{
    $('.headerComm').hide();
}
```

Comment: What does the first line means and what is it for? appending the content?

Comment: @Gwen Well you didn't posted the code that "show the table on the DOM" so I had to improvise. But yeah, you should add the condition right after you show the created table!

Comment: @Gwen could you post more code? like where is the table added to the DOM? The entire function may help here! (http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: This one is a pop up box with table inside. I done it in JavaScript and I guess there is no way to added to the DOM

Comment: @Gwen If you see it, it mean it is in the DOM ;) Can we see the code related to the pop up?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I solved it by amending some portion of my codes